# Pulsed Current Source Across Inductive Load

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, pulse, high-current

Just wondering if you guys have any recommendations for low voltage, high current pulsed power supply designs.

The current required is 300A for a 0.14mH inductive load with 0.088Ω of resistance. The pulse width is about 20ms with a 5 minute duty cycle.

Im trying to figure out a configuration that has the fastest rise and fall times possible. A block diagram of the design I'm trying to follow is included below, but the inner machinations of the components are still a mystery to me. Let me know if you have any ideas as to what each component would consist of.

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you looking for here?  I would normally say solid state contactor since you are asking for the fastest turn-on and turn-off times, but you have a "pulse shaping unit".

Comment: If you are dealing with low voltage/high current power supply the only choice is to use Mosfets in parallel to ensure low drop/losses. Find ones with lowest Rdson possible. Pairing them with similar Rdson can help you with current balancing.

Comment: Would a half sine current wave shape be acceptable?

Comment: What kind of rise time and flatness do you need on the current pulse?

Comment: Is there a way to lower the 88 mOhms resistance by using thicker wire? If you can get it low enough, you could dodge the requirement for a 300A power supply. Otherwise you'll probably need a bunch of LiPo's to keep that 27V constant enough during 20ms.

Comment: _"Im trying to figure out a configuration that has the **fastest rise and fall times possible**."_ -  why?

Answer (score 1):

Just a few thought and forgive me if my brain calculations are off but I don't have pen and paper or calculator at the moment.

Let's say you want the current to rise to 300 amps in 1 ms. That's a di/dt of 300,000. If inductance is 0.14 mH, the initial voltage applied from the capacitor bank needs to be at least 42 volts as per Michael Faraday's inductor law. Maybe that might surprise you because you referred to the design being low voltage initially. Then if you want the pulse to fall just as quickly, a parallel diode won't cut the mustard and, you'll find that you need a negative supply (also of 42 volts) to restore current back to 0 amps at the end of the pulse with a fall time of 1 ms.

If you then consider the resistance of the coil, you could easily account for another 27 volts on top of the 42 volts previously mentioned. So, as an absolute minimum for 1 ms you'll need a bipolar voltage supply of at least 70 odd volts.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a low tech proposal.

[image]

A low current 80V power supply charges capacitor C1 to about 80V. This voltage is decided mostly to be able to use 100V MOSFETs for switch SW1.

When SW1 closes, C1 discharges into the inductor and ramps up current quickly. C1's voltage (blue) drops until D2 conducts, and the 28V 300A power supply takes over (most likely a bunch of LiPo's) to sustain current in the inductor against its DC resistance.

When SW1 opens, D3 conducts to dump stored energy into capacitor C2 which has been pre-charged to 80V, so it drops the inductor current quickly. Then, C2 slowly discharges back into the input cap via R3 to recycle some of the energy.

C2 could be replaced with something else that can dissipate the energy while imposing enough reverse voltage on the inductor to quickly drop its current.

This is simple, low-tech, and easy to drive (one low side switch) but of course the drawbacks are that current is not adjustable because it is set by the 300A power supply voltage, and pulse flatness will depend on the match between inductor value and capacitor C1. If C1 is too large, it will overshoot.

Comment: I just changed some values for faster "rise time". Anyway, very good idea. https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrANj.png  I think current may be set by switch resistance when closed, so just vary this resistor.

Answer (score 0):

The time constant of the inductor for 64% current from a step voltage is
T(64%) = L/R = 140 uH / (88m +5m)ohm = 1.5 ms for 1/(2pi*T64%) ~  106 Hz -3dB BW

using math VL(t) = LdI/dt + I*DCR
if dI= 300A, L= 140 uH, **dt=L/R= 1.5ms rise time**, DCR=93 mohm

The steady state **VL= 300A * 93 mohm ~ 28V**  and **P= 8.37 kW**

The total energy is E = 0.5LI^2 +{I^2DCR * t(PW50)} =  6.3 J stored + **4.185 kJ heat**

This tells me your paramater assumptions are of concern. ( problem)

**This says after 2 ms you are not storing much more energy , just dumping it in heat.**

What's the real problem you want to solve?